# Align form elements

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create an form for inputting an appointment.

I want it to render like this:

```
Title [input]
When [input]
[] Repeat...
```

Where [ ] should illustrate a checkbox and [input] should illustrate input fields og type text.

Below is my html and css:

```css
.align {
  clear: left;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  width: 30%;
}
input[type=text],
select {
  clear: right;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
#repeat {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  width: 30%;
}
#repeat_text {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="dialog-form" title="Create new appointment">
  <form>
    <label class="align" for="title">Title</label>
    <input type="text" name="title" id="title">
    <label class="align" for="when">When</label>
    <input type="text" name="when" id="when">

    <input id="repeat" type="checkbox">
    <label id="repeat_text" for="repeat">Repeat...</label>
    <div id="repeat_properties">
      ...
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

The problem is that my #repeat and #repeat_text elements keep moving up next to my other two other form elements. Anyone got an idea about how to make them render properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Add the rule `clear: left;` on the #repeat class

2) Remove width from the #repeat class

```
#repeat
{
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    clear: left;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/0vrownkc/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this layout is to wrap every pair of `label` and `input` tags in a `p` tag.

No modifications required in CSS if you do this.

```js
.align {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    width: 30%;
    text-align: left;
}

input[type="text"], select {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    clear: right;
}

#repeat
{
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    text-align: left;
}
#repeat_text
{
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="dialog-form" title="Create new appointment">
  <form>
    <p><label class="align" for="title">Title</label>
    <input class="align" type="text" name="title" id="title"></p>
    
    <p><label class="align" for="when">When</label>
    <input class="align" type="text" name="when" id="when"></p>

    <p><input id="repeat" type="checkbox">
    <label for="repeat">Repeat...</label></p>
    <div id="repeat_properties">
      ...
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the layout using floats alone as simple as follows:

```css
input,
label {
  float: left;
}
.align {
  clear: left;
  width: 30%;
  text-align: left;
}
#repeat {
  clear: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="dialog-form" title="Create new appointment">
  <form>
    <label for="title" class="align">Title</label>
    <input type="text" id="title" name="title">
    <label for="when" class="align">When</label>
    <input type="text" id="when" name="when">
    <input type="checkbox" id="repeat">
    <label for="repeat">Repeat...</label>
    <div id="repeat_properties">
      ...
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```